# How to delete an app from iOS Xcode Simulator?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

Just in case, we can delete apps by resetting contents and settings but an individual app could also be deleted from simulator in Xcode 7. This is not the case in Xcode 8. How can this be achieved? I have a forced touch trackpad, does it affect deleting the app from simulator?

Answer (score 133, accepted):

I struggled with this too for a while until I figured it out. I'm surprised at how hard it is to find information about this...

As you mentioned, this is only an issue when using a trackpad that supports Force Click. @pingkai.tse's answer is a good one, but for me turning off "Use TrackPad Force" does not persist - I have to turn it off every time I restart the simulator.

The trick is to click without triggering a Force Click gesture. It's hard at first, but after some practice you'll get the hang of it. On the trackpad, click **very lightly** on the app and hold long enough to trigger the long press. While holding, if you see the text starting to blur you are applying too much pressure and are instead triggering a Force Click.

Comment: It took me a few tries to get it right! But finally got the hang of it :)

Comment: This is so great.... one of the more seemingly superstitious answers I've ever seen on StackOverflow but works perfectly!

Answer (score 79):

- Open the Simulator.
- Find the "Hardware" tab on the tool view.
- Undo "Touch Pressure & Use TrackPad Force".

Answer (score 67):

For iOS 11+ simulator you should long press the app icon :)

For iOS 13+ simulator you can long press the app icon. When "Rearrange apps" suggestion appears you can tap on it or continue holding the mouse button until its automatically applied

Before iOS 11: hold **alt**, then press the touch pad.

Comment: It's also worth emphasising that you have to "click" the Trackpad so you get haptic feedback. If you have _Tap to click_ turned on, a long tap doesn't do anything. It has to be hard enough to count as a "click".

Comment: @amagain you should change the accepted answer to this

Comment: Exactly! Shift + Option (which is alt) lights up the "spots", then you can tap and hold over the app you want to delete. Icons start shaking as you would expect. Then Shift + Command + H to restore order.

Answer (score 13):

Step 1: On simulator, go to home screen with command + shift + H

Step 2: Click + hold on the app icon, release when an "x" button appears at the top left of the icon

Step 3: Click on the "x" button and choose Delete for any apps you want to delete

Step 4: When finished, press command + shift + H again to return the simulator to its normal state

With a Force Touch trackpad, just make sure you don't press it all the way down when clicking on the icon.  Use a normal click.

Comment: That works only with a mouse, using a force touch trackpad on a macbook pro doesn't replicate the same result.

Answer (score 8):

1) Click on simulator

2) On the top click on Hardware and then click on Erase all content and settings

[image]

Answer (score 6):

This will uninstall the app from the booted simulator.

```
xcrun simctl uninstall booted com.app.identifier
```

Based on `simctl` I have created a script [RemoveIOSAppsScript](https://github.com/InderKumarRathore/RemoveIOSAppsScript) that deletes all the non apple apps from the booted simulator.

Answer (score 0):

You have 3d touch enabled, tap and hold "**VERY**" lightly (just feel the click, than maintain that force or less) on the app icon on the Simulator's home... Or in the System preferences, disable the "Force click and haptic feedback", than go back on the Simulator's home and keep clicked on app icon to delete it. 
I prefere the second because I can't find useful this feature of my mac.

Answer (score 0):

1. press command + space and search the X-code
2. then press the enter then Opening Simulator.
3. in Simulator top of the bar Find the "Hardware" tab on the tool view.
4. click on Undo "Touch Pressure & Use TrackPad Force".

Answer (score 0):

Just click and hold the app icon with the force touch track pad enabled... Newer MBPs work well with the simulator in my experience. If not follow the advice above.

Answer (score 0):

For appleTv simulator:

1. Press Enter over the app you want to remove.
2. When it starts moving, tap on Space
3. You will see a new menu with the delete option there!